# How to automatically name bins which count values, looping through a range in Python

Tags: python

I have some variables and want to put them in a set number of evenly sized bins, the output being the count of the number of variables in each bin. I set a minimum and maximum value, with variables less than the minimum value being put in an ‘ignore’ bin. I then calculate the width of the bins based on the number of bins I want to fit between the maximum and minimum values, setting an upper and lower boundary for each bin, so I know which bin the variable goes in. Variables greater than the maximum value are completely ignored.

I get that far fine, but what I have problems with is automating the process that names the bins and counts how many variables go in each bin. I have used range() to  go through the required number of bins. But I can’t figure out in Python how to label the different bins and store the counts there. I have seen on the forum .count() and .sum, but I can’t adapt them to this situation, of changing the bin name as it goes through the loop.

The code so far is (where values is the list of variables I have and B is the number of bins I want):

```
import numpy as np
import statistics

def median_bins(values, B):
  ignore = 0
  means = np.mean(values)
  stddev = np.std(values)
  minval = means - stddev
  maxval = means + stddev
  width = (2*stddev)/B
  for val in values:
    if val < minval:
      ignore = ignore+1
    else:
      for i in range(0,B):
        bin_i = 0
        if minval + i*width < val < minval + (i+1)*width:
          bin_i = bin_i + 1
        else:
          continue
  return(means, stddev, ignore, count)
```

I would like to bin_i to automatically label itself bin_1, bin_2, etc and store the counts.

Thanks very much

Comment: to me that sounds like you want to use a dictionary

Comment: Exacly my though. Creating many viariable bin_i, wll make your code a mess. Instead you want to create `bin_dict = {}` and store those values there `bin_dict[i] = value`

Comment: OK. I'll try that. Thanks